# Xcode suddenly quit in runtime when parsing JSON

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

I'm trying to parse JSON with struct :

this is the JSON looks alike (the object value on SEAT has more than 100):

```
{
    "Message": "Success",
    "Status": 200,
    "data": {
        "SEATS": [          
            {
                "SEAT_LOC_NO": "01404301",                  
                "ROW_NM": "A",                  
                "SEAT_NO": 1
            },
            {
                "SEAT_LOC_NO": "01404401",                  
                "ROW_NM": "A",                  
                "SEAT_NO": 2
            }
        ],
        "SEATCOUNT": {
            "COL_CNT": 42,              
            "ROW_CNT": 12,
        }
    }
}
```

and my struct be like:

```
struct Response : Codable {
  var data : datas?
  var Message : String?
  var Status : Int64?
}

struct datas : Codable {
  var SEATS : [SEATS]?
  var SEATCOUNT : SEATINFO?
}

struct SEATS : Codable {
  var SEAT_LOC_NO : String?
  var ROW_NM : String?
  var SEAT_NO : String?
}

struct SEATINFO : Codable {
  var COL_CNT : Int64?
  var ROW_CNT : Int64?
}
```

and this is the process of parsing:

```
var getSeat = Response()
getSeat = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: json) as Response
```

The xcode exit when trying to run this progress, `json` is a `Data` type which has been called in API Service.

I've been trying to delete derived data, remove some data in xcodeproject, restarting xcode and OS. However this problem still comes. And I wonder why but only on this process xcode suddenly quit while the others process is fine (different data to parse).

I'm using the latest XCODE Version.

Is it a bug, failed parsing or something else?

Comment: What is type of var data : datas?, Can you explain which of super class of datas.

Comment: it is another struct (the below of Response)

Comment: First of all, you might want to change your names to stick to the Swift  naming conventions. I. e. type names have an uppercase initial while variable names start with a lowercase letter. Also, you might want to refrain from using all-uppercased names. These rules will immediately improve readability of your code and allow people to better help you.

Comment: thanks i'll try. but the problem is why xcode suddenly quit and didn't give any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `"SEAT_NO"` key is integer value. You declare it as `String?` in struct.

Change `var SEAT_NO : String?` to `var SEAT_NO : Int?` or value in `"SEAT_NO"` key to String

If there is more problems try to catch errors

```
do {
    getSeat = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried on JSON which you post or on another?

Comment: been trying to parse another JSON and works well. while this one caused problem, dunno why but xcode suddenly quit without giving any error message

Comment: ah i found the problem which caused Xcode quit. it was my parsing using `try!` and after change to `try?` it doesn't quit but the struct giving nil result

Answer (score 0):

@Vanillatte  please check your JSON first it's not valid please remove extra semicolon seat count dictionary. and try and to use error handling during parsing response.

[image]